# Possible to pass variable to regex literal then capture match group to another local variable?

Tags: ruby, regex

In order to save [regex capture groups](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) to a local variable, the regex must be on the left side of an operation such as `/(?<somegroup>someregex)/ =~ 'somestring'`. For example, given a url string, extracting the top level domain:

```
/(?<extract>\b.com\b)[\/]{0,1}/ =~ 'google.com'
puts extract # => .com
```

There are various domains (.org, .scb, .wine, .me, etc). My strategy is to store [all possible tlds from a reputable source](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db) in an array, and iterate through each one and pass it to the regex. How do you pass a variable to the literal?

Here is a simplified method of what I am trying to do:

```
def example_extract(url_str)
  exmpl = '.com'
  regx = /(?<extract>\b#{exmpl}\b)[\/]{0,1}/
  regx =~ url_str
  extract
end

example_extract('google.com')
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `extract' for main:Object
```

I fail to pass a variable to a left hand (literal) regex operation. Why is my capture group `extract` not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the documentation for [Regexp#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E), it says:

> This assignment is implemented in the Ruby parser. The parser detects ‘regexp-literal =~ expression’ for the assignment. The regexp must be a **literal without interpolation** and placed at left hand side.

The reason local variable was not assigned is because your regex was defined using interpolation, and is not a literal.

As the citation implies, assigning a local variable is done during parsing phase, and since string interpolation is done during run time, there seems no way to detour the limitation imposed by the specification.

Comment: hmmmm... looks like the answer to this question is a big fat **not possible**.  Marking as complete and opening another question on the way ahead.  Thanks @sawa.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's future reference. You have to use regexp's `MatchData`. This is what worked for me:

```
def example_extract(url_str)
  exmpl = '.com'
  regx = /(?<extract>\b#{exmpl}\b)[\/]{0,1}/
  extract = regx.match(url_str)[:extract]
  p extract
end

example_extract('google.com')
```